# Can a single boto3 dynamodb client update multiple tables simultaneously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

```
client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
```

I would like to know if I am able to use batchwriteitem to 2 tables with this client simultaneously, or should I create another client? Can dynamodb even handle simultaneous updates for different tables?

Comment: Try it and let us know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same client to write or delete items in two or more tables at the same time, [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item)

> The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client("dynamodb")

response = client.batch_write_item(
    RequestItems={
        "table_1": [
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "Key": {
                            "S": "key1",
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "Key": {
                            "S": "key2",
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        ],
        "table_2": [
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "Key": {
                            "S": "key1",
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                "PutRequest": {
                    "Item": {
                        "Key": {
                            "S": "key2",
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity="TOTAL",
)

# output
{'UnprocessedItems': {}, 'ConsumedCapacity': [{'TableName': 'table_1', 'CapacityUnits': 2.0}, {'TableName': 'table_2', 'CapacityUnits': 2.0}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'XXX', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Fri, 06 Aug 2021 01:53:43 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '132', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'XXX', 'x-amz-crc32': '123'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```